# How to make private route? How to get token?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem:

After login submit I get token from console.log code ->

```
axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
        axios.post(`api/login`, data).then((res) => {
            if (res.data.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem("auth_token", res.data.token);
                localStorage.setItem("auth_name", res.data.fullname);
                navigate("/");
            } else if (res.data.status === 401) {
                navigate("/login");
            } else {
                setLogin({ ...loginInput, error_list: res.data.validation_errors });
            }
            const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
            const isAuth = token ? true : false;

            <Router token={token} isAuth={isAuth} />;
            console.log(token);
        });
    });
```

Router file ->

```
const Router = (props) => {
   const token = props.token;
   const isAuth = props.isAuth;

   console.log(token);

   return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoute isAuth={isAuth} />}>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route path="/recover" element={<Recover />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   );
};
```

And this is ProtectedRoute.js file ->

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuth }) => {
          return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
     };

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Can anyone help me to make a condition to check if user have token (is logged) or not to navigate him.